# Background image not displaying in Outlook.com

Tags: html, css, email

Not sure if I'm making a syntax error but I can't get this email background image to display in Outlook.com. It does display in gmail and in Outlook desktop app.

```
<tr class="module" data-id="B1" data-description="B1 Large email heading">
                        
<td role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" valign="top" style="max-width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse;" class="">

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block; width: 600pt; height: 495pt;" src="https://picsum.photos/600/495" />                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 600pt; height:495pt;">
<v:fill  opacity="0%" color="#ffffff”  />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->

<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px; mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt:0px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/600/495'); background-position: bottom left; background-size:cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; max-width: 600px;text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 21px; color: rgb(100, 114, 127); padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;" background="https://picsum.photos/600/495" width="600" height="495" valign="top">
                                
<h2 style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal;margin:10px 0 0px 0;">CEO INSIGHT</h2>
<h2 style="color:#d11418; font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal;margin:0px 0 5px 0;">MATT JERSEY</h2>
    
<p style="width:70%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut porta odio. In semper massa nec dictum aliquet. Phasellus dui nisi, faucibus a purus in, varius luctus elit. Praesent eleifend gravida pellentesque. </p>
    
<p style="width:70%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut porta odio. In semper massa nec dictum aliquet. Phasellus dui nisi, faucibus a purus in, varius luctus elit. Praesent eleifend gravida pellentesque. </p>
    
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:fill>
</v:rect>
</v:image>
<![endif]-->
                         
</td>
    

</tr>
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to see what HTML is output in the Outlook.com email for comparison. Also you can look at the DOM structure in the developer tools to see if it's as you expect.

Comment: This is the <td> with the image. Maybe this is helpful: <td data-imagetype="External" background="/actions/ei?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimage.engage.srtenics.com%2Flib%2Ffe36157075640475711276%2Fm%2F1%2F8dd06e14-148c-4825-82ce-705058f5c6b1.jpg&amp;d=2023-09-25T03%3A40%3A43.951Z" originalsrc="http://image.engage.srtenics.com/lib/fe36157075640475711276/m/1/8dd06e14-148c-4825-82ce-705058f5c6b1.jpg" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" height="495" valign="top">

Comment: I'm guessing that it's doing that to ensure you're not using the background-image to confirm that the email has been read (by generating a unique image URL per email address). That allows spammers to confirm they've found a real address and should start spamming it relentlessly. As such you probably shouldn't link to an external image and should instead embed the images you need.